# Creating a playlist in iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, playlist, mpmediaquery

Is it possible to create, name and save an iTunes playlist like you can in the Music app from a 3rd-party programmed app? If so, how?

Comment: Does the app have to be approved by Apple? Or can you use private APIs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

iTunes playlists (`MPMediaPlaylist`) are read-only, so there is currently no way to create these through a 3rd-party app. The user can only do this with iTunes or through the built-in iOS Music app.